# separador de miles en angular 4

Tags: angular4, pipe

estoy usando angular 4 y quiero poder usar un pipe de separador de miles
por ejemplo si el monto es 6000 que aparezca 6.000, si el monto es 60000 que aparezca 60.000 y asi...

he intentado usar algunos pipes pero no logro dar con uno que me sirva, para mostrar el monto utilizo un

```
 ngFor="let item of items"
```

y en la parte que muestro el monto puse

```
{{item.Monto/1000 | currency:'USD':true:'2.3-3'}}
```

con eso me aparece el monto como `06.000` en vez de `6.000`

Comment: te invito a leer un poco mas de [angular y los formatos](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

Comment: cambia el 2.3-3 por 1.3-3

Comment: Efectivamente me funciona, me aparece 60.000 y 6.000 pero al poner un monto de 600 me aparece como 0.600 , de todos modos se agradece la disposición y respuesta rápida

Comment: Lo de (0.600) te sucede porque es para poner el separador de parte fraccionaria (la , en nuestro idioma), no de miles. Por eso de denomina "DecimalPipe", prueba con 6.000.000 (6 millones) y solo deberías ver 6000.000

Comment: intenta con 3-3, el problema es que lo que estas haciendo estas definiciendo una mascara y dice 0.000

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el siguiente **Pipe**:

> Cada 3 dígitos inserta un "."(punto) mediante la expresión regular

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
        name: 'thousandsPipe'
    })

export class ThousandsPipe implements PipeTransform {

    public transform(value: any) {
        return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");;
    }
}
```

En el **HTML**:

```
{{item.Monto/1000 | thousandsPipe}}
```

> Dato importante, esto **solo** agrega la separación de miles, no la decimal ni la moneda.

---

### Información Adicional:

En cuanto al Pipe propio de Angular que utilizas, funciona de la siguiente forma:

```
variable_numero | number[:digitInfo]
```

`digitInfo` esta constituido de la siguiente forma:

```
{cantMinDigitosEnteros}.{cantMinDigitosDecimales}-{cantMaxDigitosDecimales}
```

> **CurrencyPipe**, y **DecimalPipe**, recaen sobre el mismo funcionamiento, varían en la posibilidad de insertar el tipo de moneda y lo que eso implica.